# How to give chrome extension permission to change protection pages

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, accessibility

I am using dark reader extention and sometimes I stumble on pages protected by browser or settinfs pages which gives my eyes white theme shock which hurts

[image]

Comment: Google intentionally prevents themes & extensions from modifying certain pages (such as `chrome://flags`). The combination of the Morpheon Dark theme & the Dark Reader extension are said to be the closest.

Comment: Dark reader [is aware of the issue](https://github.com/darkreader/darkreader/issues/487#issuecomment-393146989), but claims [„adding newtab to site list“](https://github.com/darkreader/darkreader/issues/487#issuecomment-393146989) would be a solution. (Which is not true, as far as I can tell. Especially in conjunction with the wonderfull [„Blank New Tab Page“](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blank-new-tab-page/jonikckfpolfcdcgdficelkfffkloemh))